# Woocommerce - get product in category with specific attribute

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to get all product in a category that match an attribute.

Here my code:

```
$title     = isset($instance['title']) ? $instance['title'] : '';
$car_type  = isset($instance['cartype']) ? $instance['cartype'] : 'usato';
$car_brand = isset($instance['carbrand']) ? $instance['carbrand'] : '';
$limit     = isset($instance['limit']) ? $instance['limit'] : null;
$order     = $instance['order'];
$carousel  = $instance['carousel'];


$query_args = [
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'product_cat' => $car_type                
 ];

 // Ordino i risultati
 if ($order == 'random') {
     $query_args['orderby'] = 'random';
 } else {
     $query_args['orderby'] = 'name';
     $query_args['order']   = $order;
 }

 // Devo limitare il numero di risultati?
 if ($limit) {
     $query_args['posts_per_page'] = $limit;
 }

 if ($car_brand != '') {
     $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
         array(
             'key'     => 'pa_marca',
             'value'   => 'nike',
             'field'   => 'slug',
             'compare' => '='
         )
     );
 }
```

The problem is that I always get 0 result even if there is a product with that category and that attribute.
How should I modify the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get the solution, this is how you need to query on an attribute:

```
$query_args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'pa_brand',
        'field'   => 'slug',
        'terms'   => 'nike'
    )
);
```

Note that in the key you need to add pa_ to your attribute name and you need to use terms to specify the value of your attribute.